# Cant upload MySQL file to cpanel gives contains virus error

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I am trying to upload a backup of the MySQL database exported file to the Cpanel public_html folder. upon upload I am getting the following error:

The file you uploaded, MySQL_file_name.zip, contains a virus so the upload was canceled: antispamcloud.score.medium.abusedredirector14.UNOFFICIAL FOUND

I scanned the file with an antivirus online and on my computer but it didn't find any virus on it.

Regards,

Comment: what application exactly is printing that error? some ftp client?

Comment: On the browser itself, no ftp client.

Comment: you mean chrome/firefox is giving you that error? or phpmyadmin?

Comment: @the_nuts Yes on browsers

Comment: so try with another browser, maybe it's an extension...

Comment: Check for the virus here https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload If you get no virus here, contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding .sql as file extension?

You can contact your server provider. permissions may be turned off.

Comment: Yes tried that also

Answer (score 0):

Your .zip file contains, most likely, a single .sql file.  Try extracting the .sql file from the .zip file and then upload that to phpmyadmin. If it goes through, you're all set.

If your hosting provider's phpmyadmin also rejects the extracted .sql file there are a couple of possibilities.  (It's phpmyadmin that's looking for viruses.)

1. Some cybercreep successfully attacked the WordPress site you backed up and put some nasty malware in one of your tables. Your hosting provider's phpmyadmin detected it when you uploaded your backup. (That's good, if frustrating.)

   Maybe you can scan the WordPress site you backed up in the first place and find the nasty stuff. Sucuri's a plugin for that. Then you'll have to recreate the database backup.
2. It's a false-positive virus detection. Ask your hosting provider for help.